# Compiling Class Member Variables Out with C++ Templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compiler-errors

I have a class that looks similar to this:

```
class Compound
{
    void* pValue0;
    void* pValue1;
    void* pValue2;
    void* pValue3;
    void* pValue4;
    void* pValue5;
    void* pValue6;
    void* pValue7;
    void* pValue8;
    void* pValue9;
    void* pValueA;
    void* pValueB;
    void* pValueC;
};
```

When I create a new Compound class, I allocate extra memory [sizeof(Compound) + extraSpace]. Each of the pValue's refer to an address in the extra memory.

Now, I would like to reduce the number of pValue's depending on which of them I need. Templates seem like a good fit.

So if I wanted a class Compound<0A>, I would only want pValue0 and pValueA, and then have the compiler remove all other pValues. Essentially, I would want it to then become:

```
template <uint Mask = 0A>
class Compound<Mask>
{
    void* pValue0;
    void* pValueA;
}
```

Is this possible? I got close with enable_if, but when I tried to limit it to a particular mask the compiler threw errors about being unable to find a type when the enable_if case was false.

Thank you all!

Comment: Why not a class with a list of pointers?

Comment: How is this different from storing all your values in a `std::vector`? You can get a `pValue0` anytime you need by `&v[0]`.

Comment: You could achieve what you want by using the [empty member optimization](http://www.cantrip.org/emptyopt.html) combined with `std::conditional` (to switch to an empty type when the condition is false). That would be ugly though.

Comment: @BoPersson, the only problem with that is that in practice all of the pValue's will be pointers to other classes defined with their type and not just void*.

Comment: The integer `0A` is the same integer as the integer `A`.

Comment: Use multiple classes and inheritance

Comment: @Yakk, `0A` is an example for a mask, not the actual value. It was shorter than writing Mask0 | MaskA.

Comment: Your question limits our ability to understand what you're attempting to do. It represents a design choice we can't see or realize. Must of us know from experience, and the literature, that while there are occasional uses for void *, sometimes by necessity, in most cases it is not only unnecessary, but bad design, fraught with peril, with far better solutions available elsewhere. So, it would help greatly if we had some reason to bother saying something other than this is a bad idea, by know what you're really doing and why you feel a collection of void * is the way to do it.

Comment: BTW, you could use a template taking an unsigned int (or int) which declares the size of an array of void pointers (see source of std::array, for example)

Comment: @pantaryl Please try to make code that is as close as you can get to solving your problem.  Pseudo code that isn't properly labelled is worse than useless, and psuedo code that is labelled only sometimes marginally more useful than English prose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do:

```
template<char...>
struct flags_tag {constexpr flags_tag(){}; };

template<char...Cs>
struct make_flags{ using type=flags_tag<Cs...>; };
template<char...Cs>
struct make_flags<'0','x',Cs...>:make_flags<Cs...>{};
template<char...Cs>
struct make_flags<'0','X',Cs...>:make_flags<Cs...>{};
template<char...Cs>
using make_flags_t = typename make_flags<Cs...>::type;

template<char...Cs>
constexpr make_flags_t<Cs...> operator""_flag(){ return {}; }

template<char> struct pValue_t;
template<> struct pValue_t<'0'>{ void* pValue0 = 0; };
template<> struct pValue_t<'1'>{ void* pValue1 = 0; };
// ...
template<> struct pValue_t<'A'>{ void* pValueA = 0; };
template<> struct pValue_t<'B'>{ void* pValueB = 0; };
template<> struct pValue_t<'C'>{ void* pValueC = 0; };

template<class flags>
struct Compound;

template<char...Cs>
struct Compound< flags_tag<Cs...> >:
  pValue_t<Cs>...
{};
```

Then you use it like:

```
using my_type = Compound< decltype( 0x0A_flag ) >;
int main() {
  my_type test;
  std::cout << test.pValue0 << test.pValueA << '\n';
}
```

which seems to do what you want.

I'd also disable the copy/move ctor of your `Compound` type, and make its other constructors `private` with a `friend` factory function.

Note that this code can generate an exponential number of classes (2^12, or 4k), and that can cause binary bloat (if any per-class code isn't inlined out of existence).

[live example]

Comment: This works!

Can you explain why this part is necessary?:

`template<char...Cs>
constexpr make_flags_t<Cs...> operator""_flag(){ return {}; }`

I couldn't figure out why this part in particular is necessary. I tried doing  `template<char...Cs>
constexpr make_flags_t<Cs...> operator_test(){ return {}; }`
but that wouldn't work.

What is necessary about the `_flag` part?

Comment: @pantaryl It was my attempt to get as close to the `Compound<0A>` syntax as I could.  A user-defined literal `_flag` that consumes the characters of an integer like this: `0x0A_flag` -- that is what `template<char...> operator""` does.  We then take its type (which contains the hex characters) and feed it to `Compound< decltype( 0x0A_flag ) >`.  You could do it with `Compound< decltype( operator_test<'0', 'A'>() >` or other similar syntax, like `Compound< flags_tag< '0', 'A' > >`.

Comment: I've changed the implementation to [link](http://pastebin.ca/3164976).

However, it refuses to compile unless `operator_test` is renamed as `operator_flag`. Any idea why?

Comment: @pantaryl Other than typos, undefined behavior, types not in evidence, lack of `constexpr` keywords, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42077c5aa6556058 -- it seems to work?  I saw no need for `operator_test` to even exist in that version?  And `operator""_flag` is a completely different beast than `operator_test` or `operator_flag`.  Please, if you are going to quote code at me, provide the actual code that actually generates the error in question -- I wasted another 5 minutes fixing errors in your pastebin that where completely unrelated to renaming `operator_test`.

Comment: Ok, I've cleaned it up some. [LINK](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/692c02802b3b8320)

See the commented out section that I say is the problem: Do you know of a way to be able to reference possible member variables in member functions, but have the logic compiled out when the StateMask isn't valid?

Comment: You can't compile out methods conditionally in a direct way (except in a deduced context), but you can swap out types (for say, a base class) which might have different/fewer methods.

Comment: @VoidStar, my existing code is able to, while using the `IsStateValid(std::uint32_t mask)` compile out code that is not used. However, it can't seem to compile out the understanding of the variable if it knows that it isn't being used.

I've verified via debugging compiled code that the assembly generated for `IsStateValid()` will disappear if the statement is false for a given template.

Comment: @pantaryl If you have another question, please ask it.  The button is right above: this area is for comments and requests for clarifications, not new questions.  I'd first search for it, as I suspect there are many answers to that question already on stack overflow.

Comment: Yes, unreferenced code should not be built, I thought you meant making the method unavailable to even accidentally call. BTW member fields are never compiled out.

Answer (score 2):

`std::conditional` is similar to `std::enable_if`, except conditional always returns a type.

`std::conditional<satisfies(Mask), void*, EmptyClass>` would be the way to swap the member's types out conditionally and have it compile.

The problem is, C++ does not allow empty members. The size will be 1. To solve this problem, you'd need the [empty member optimization](http://www.cantrip.org/emptyopt.html). This will achieve the memory layout that you're asking for, but unfortunately, this will make the class members difficult to read. You can add accessor functions to mitigate this, if you think it's worth pursuing.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the `Compound` class shall contain pointers to objects of different classes and not void pointers, as you said in your comment.

I don't know if that is a good idea because I think there is something wrong in the design, but you could use tuples and template specializations on `ints` to select the type you want:

```
class Class0;
class ClassA;

template<int> struct Compound {};
template<> struct Compound<0A> 
{
    typedef std::tuple<Class0*, ClassA*> type;
}
// other mapping from mask to type

typename Compound<0A>::type aCompund(ptr0, ptrA);
```